# Loop through "mount binded" directories and match ones you want to unbind

Tags: shell, loops

I know how to list mounted directories and I know how to umount them.

Being a noob with shell scripts is there a way to take the output of `mount` ... loop through the list and match each entry with a given variable (/some/random/path) and a execute a command on that matched entry.

Nothing complex just a simple loop as it where or a pointer in the right direction.

Note: The code/task I have is more complicated so this is simply how to loop in shell.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 1):

To match all bind-mounts, I'd use `awk '$NF ~ /bind/ { print }`

The field is usually the sixth ($6), but this would fail with mounts with spaces, where NF (number of fields) comes in to play. Since the options are listed lastly.

If you are certain there won't be spaces (which will become trouble some for other parts), I'd go with `$6`.

I't not clear weather you want the "source" or "target" of the mount, replace `print` with `print $<N>` where `<N>` is the field you want. 1 for source (like a device or the directory you bound from) and 3 for the target - But as I said, if there are spaces in the names of the target, this will be troublesome.

I think you should be able to parse `/etc/mtab` as well. Using that and assuming you want the target-name and have no nasty spaces, try:

```
for target in $(awk '$4 ~ /bind/ {print $2}' /etc/mtab); do 
    echo "Doing stuff to $target"
done
```

**Edit**: You can, of course, add the `match ones you want to unbind` to awk.
Example: `awk '$4 ~ /bind/ && $2 ~ /(dir1|dir2)/ { ...` etc.

You say you want to perform complex operations, but if you were just interested in unmounting all bind-mounts which also are available in fstab, `umount -a -O bind` will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
for directory in $(mount | awk '{print $1}'); do
    #whatever with $directory
done
```

(I suppose your mount command returns the directory as a first entry)